# Will this VWP stamp be reset upon returning to the US?

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program

My boyfriend came to the US from April 3 to April 13.

He wants to come back in May and use the rest of his 80 days since he gets 90 days in the US under the Visa Waiver Program, however we are having trouble understanding the stamp.

Does this stamp mean he has only until July 1st to be in the US, even though he left before that, or will they restamp his passport with a new date he has to leave by if he comes back?[image: photo of UK passport with a US "Admitted APR 03 2022 Class Until JUL 01 2022" stamp]

Answer (score 16):

The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) allows eligible nationals to stay in the US for *up to* 90 days without applying for a visa. The 90 days resets each time a VWP visitor is granted entry. So unless he is currently in Canada, Mexico or the Caribbean, he will get a new stamp next time, assuming he is granted entry.

Comment: How does CBP know when he left the US on his first visit?

Comment: @philfreedenberg The US does not use exit stamps. If he left by air, the airline would have sent his details to CBP electronically when he left so his exit could be recorded. This can be [confirmed by checking his I-94 record online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home). If he entered by air and exited via the land border, to oversimplify, there are some scenarios in which the exit may not be recorded, and [it is useful to have evidence of the date he entered Canada or Mexico](https://helpspanish.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1674?language=en_US) in case this happened.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Traveller's correct answer:

In 2002 my (European) family travelled to Australia via Canada and Hawai'i; the Air Canada flight left Vancouver, landed in Honolulu in the middle of the night, passengers disembarked, passed through immigration, went back to the same gate and boarded the same plane onto Sydney. The same happened in reverse on our flight back. I was still in high school so I don't remember all of the details exactly.

As we are eligible for the VWP, we got the same stamps into our passport. There was also some additional paper slip in there. On our outbound trip, somebody at the gate noticed that the stamp and/or slip said '90 days', asked us when our return flight was scheduled (in about 12 days) and came to the conclusion that it's fine, they'll leave the slips in there so we can re-use them.

However, when we came back through Hawai'i on our return trip, the immigration agent was, let's say, very unhappy about this, asked us a lot of questions about whether and when we actually left the US and concluded that said agent 'is in for a big fine'.

So basically, you leave the US and your VWP entry is completed; new entry, new stamp.

Comment: As an American, I'm [*shocked*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjbPi00k_ME) to discover that CBP can't consistently enforce its own policies.

Comment: I understand the irony from which your "shocked" statement originates.  Unless something changed a lot over the latter portions of the post-9/11 period, nothing could possibly shock me about CBP or USCIS. We immigrated from Canada in the 90s (initially on TNs, then green cards, eventually naturalizing about 5 years after 9/11).  I cycled through 9 statuses my first year in the US (I was doing gig work on a TN - the officers would often doubt the temporary nature of my 2 month contract). I don't think any two INS encounters were the same.  Even my very last engagement with USCIS left me aghast.

Comment: @Kevin the agent in question would have been an airline agent, not a CBP agent: at the time VWP visitors would get a paper I-94W stapled in the passport on entry, and the airline was supposed to take that on exit (there is no CBP exit check) and give it to CBP so they would know who exited the US (or didn’t). The whole thing was quite dysfunctional.

Comment: When I began working on a TN in the 90's, was traveling frequently and left it to the airline to decide whether to take the I-94 form or not I got crap from the CBP on about every other entry for either still having the I-94 when I shouldn't have or not having it when I should have. I eventually looked up the rules myself and told the airline agent what to do to avoid that. The current (mostly) paperless system, which no longer depends on airline employees to do the right thing, is much better.